# "Application has stopped unexpectedly" error when starting Play Store or browser. How to fix?

Tags: system-error, google-apps

How to fix the `application Google Services Framework (process com.google.process.gapps) has stopped unexpectedly` error? It's showing like 10,000 times and I can't get into the Play Store or the browser.

Comment: If you could give a few more details, we might be able to help you. Do you e.g. get a "force-close" popup, or is the message just a "toast"? Have you tried the usual steps like e.g. clearing cache/data from affected apps, or re-booting your device?

Comment: Possibly related: [Have to clear google services framework on android ice cream sandwich](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/37851)

Comment: Have you updated recently? Have you tried clearing the cache from the app? Clearing the data? Please add these details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I find that rebooting and clearing the cache will sometimes clear the app from stopping. If that doesn't work, then I uninstall the app and re-install the app back later.

Comment: Its a pain the ass when the apps stop in the middle of your downloading or texting.